# Show that there is no real solution outside the interval $[-1, 2]$

Tags: calculus

Consider the equation

$x^4 − x^2 − x + 1 = \sin(x) \tag{1}$

Show that (1) has a solution in the interval $[0, 1]$, and another in the interval $[1, 2]$. [DONE]

Show that there are no real solutions of (1) with $x$ outside the interval $[−1, 2]$. The previous question may help.

---

I tried to differentiate it to prove it either increase or decrease but it doesn't work.

Comment: Outside the interval the LHS is greater than 1.

Comment: How can you prove the polynomial is greater than 1 outside [-1,2].

Comment: check endpoints

Comment: Maybe useful $$x^4-x^2-x+1=x^2(x^2-1)-(x-1)=(x-1)(x^2(x+1)-1)=(x-1)(x^3+x^2-1)$$